# regex match behaviour, why is it returning the rest of the string

Tags: python, regex

```
Year_month_day=re.match("(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})",time_string)
if (Year_month_day):
    Year_month_day=Year_month_day.string.split('-')
    temp_df.loc[i-1,'day']=Year_month_day[1]
```

Why for the above code is `time_string='2022-10-26 12:59:06 PM'` being returned as the array
`['2022','10','26 12:59:06 PM']` and not `[['2022','10','26']`?
Shouldn't `(\d{2})` make it impossible for '26' to have 12:59:06 PM attached to it? The pattern is `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are splitting the `.string` attribute, which contains the original input string. You want to split `.group(0)` which contains the actual match.

Better yet, since you already collected the matches in groups, use them.

```
if Year_month_day:
    temp_df.loc[i-1,'day'] = Year_month_day.group(2)
```

(Your code would put the month there; if you really wanted the day, that's `.group(3)`.)